# How to Shorten Image URL in Asp.Net

Tags: mysql, asp.net

Want to shorten image url in asp.net 
My Code in Asp.net is

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("images/") + filename);
```

And It store url in my Database as

```
C:\Users\A\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\images\IMG_20190802_114524.jpg
```

I want to shorten my image url in Mysql DB

```
/image/imagename
```

Comment: Your database should have an ID column of some sort right? So use that to look up the URL e.g. `/image/123`

Answer (score 0):

The Concept of saving file URL in DB is you have to save relative path only. In your case

**let spouse:**

```
C:\Users\A\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\images\IMG_20190802_114524.jpg
```

This part is same for all images so why you are saving this in db make a constant and asign this path.

```
C:\Users\A\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite1\images\
```

Now you have to save only file name in db.

```
IMG_20190802_114524.jpg
```

So when you want to access image concatenate constant value and file name and you get image.

Hope this'll help you.

Comment: And when there are multiple folders with images? Let's say `c:\images1\foo.jpg` and `c:\images2\foo.jpg`?

Comment: If you have different folder names then save folder name as well.

Comment: Then you're basically back to the same problem OP started with.

Comment: basically you have to exclude similar part from your path you have to save different path some where to get files back.

Comment: Or you use the solution I added above as a comment, it's the only guaranteed method.